# Solved - No Wireless on Dell E7440 - Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, dell

When I boot from USB, the wireless works great. However, when I install to a partition, the wireless does not appear in the network options. When I try to access Network in the control panel, the program crashes every time. My wireless card is a Intel 7260 and it appears when I run lspci.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to either the wireless or sound issue and start a new question for the other because only one issue per question is allowed. Thanks

Comment: @JuliaKM, were you able to figure out the issue with the audio driver? When I boot into Ubuntu from USB, I don't get any audio.

Comment: @Expressions_Galore No, I never was able to get audio when booting from USB.

Comment: @JuliaKM What about after installing the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the wireless, I suggest you try the newer firmware file. First, back up the existing file:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak
```

Now download the newer file:

```
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Reboot and tell us if it works better now.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the firmware and rebooted and had wireless. I'll try the same for the audio.

Comment: @chili555 hey chill, what's up? I seem to have a wireless curse, I have this exact pc, the output of lspci was the same, but it I followed your steps and didn't help. Any way to proceed from here?